# Can an ebook really make it big?

Tags: writing

Recently, I was having a casual conversation with a friend, and I was telling them about my great idea for a book, but I had no money to have it published professionally. He told me about this platform where I could do it all myself in the form of an ebook.

I do not know exactly how big the ebook market is right now, and I would like to know if an ebook can have a realistic chance at making it big. Of course, I don't expect to become a famous author, and I understand that even if ebooks have a shot at becoming big, mine likely will not.

My question is, does an ebook really have a realistic chance at becoming big?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way can see it, yes, it can make it big. Commuting, I saw many people (of all ages) using all kinds of devices for reading books - I mean, they were actually reading - smartphones, tablets, e-ink readers... It would be perfectly natural if your book would be on their screens.

And there is more: if your book becomes even slightly successful as an e-book, then you might even find a publisher to release a paper version later. This is a big opportunity, compared to past times, when electronics did not exist at all.

On the other hand, making your (electronic) book known is another matter, which is outside the scope of the main question (ans possibly outside the scope of this site entirely).

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer. Additionally: it is customary on all StackExchange sites that if you like an answer (or question), you up-vote it. In that way, the author will get some additional reputation points.